# Notation for immediate predecessor-successor relation in a poset

Tags: notation, order-theory

Is there some standard or common notation for immediate predecessor-successor relation in a partially ordered set? How to write that $x\prec y$ and there is no $z$ such that $x\prec z\prec y$?

Answer (score 0):

a is covered by b, b covers a,
when a < b and not exists x with a < x < b.

I have seen notation somewhat like a -< b for b covers a.

In general, there is no immediate precessor or successor.
Every element may cover numerous elements or none at all.